# Calling JavaScript Function that has SetTimeout Assigned to It

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

I'm not 100% sure how setTimeout works in JavaScript. Say I have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {           
    testTimeout();        
});

function testTimeout() {
    alert("testing timeout");
    setTimeout(testTimeout, 5000);
}
```

This would display a popup window every 5 after the page is ready. What would happen if then I called testTimeout from a button click?

```
$("#button").click(function() {        
    testTimeout();
});
```

Would the button click call testTimeout and add another timeout every 5 seconds? Or, would the button click reset the timeout from when the button was pressed? The reason I am asking is because I would like to design something like this where I can pass a parameter to my timeout function. When the web page starts up, I have a default parameter. However, if I press a button, I would like my timeout function to be called right away and every 5 seconds after with my new parameter. But, I don't want the timeout function with the old parameter to continue repeating. How can I achieve this? Any help and understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"This would display a popup window every 5 after the page is ready. "* No it wouldn't, it would show an alert repeatedly with no delay.

Comment: Your alert has a syntax error

Comment: Really? That doesn't seem to be the case for me?

Comment: OP editted, a quote and a parentheses was edited (see your answer, you'll see it)

Comment: do you want to reset the timeout when you click the button or just do nothing?

Comment: I want to reset the timeout along with passing a new parameter. I also want to clear the last timeout function that was called from startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This would display a popup window every 5 after the page is ready.

No it wouldn't, it would show an alert repeatedly with no delay and/or cause a "too much recursion" error, because `setTimeout(testTimeout(), 5000)` *calls* `testTimeout` and passes its return value into `setTimeout`, just like `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

If you remove the `()`:

```
function testTimeout() {
    alert("testing timeout");
    setTimeout(testTimeout, 5000);
    // here --------------^
}
```

Then it would do that.

> What would happen if then I called testTimeout from a button click?

You'd end up with the function being called twice as often (more than once every 5 seconds), because every time you call it, it reschedules itself. A third time would make it more frequently still (three times/second), and so on.

---

If you want to avoid that, one option is to remember the timer handle and cancel any outstanding timed callback if you call the function before then:

```
var handle = 0;
function testTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(handle); // Clears the timed call if we're being called beforehand
    alert("testing timeout");
    handle = setTimeout(testTimeout, 5000);
}
```

(I initialized `handle` with `0` because calling `clearTimeout` with a `0` is a no-op.)

Comment: This script is a recursive nightmare D:

Comment: @SterlingArcher: It was as originally written, yeah. Without the `()` it's a fairly common idiom for a repeated action (the other being, of course, `setInterval`).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the () from setTimeout. So, how do I prevent it from rescheduling itself? I only want one timeout every 5 seconds. But, when I click a button, I would like to change the parameter being used in the timeout function.

Comment: @user3781214: You can do that by saving the timer handle and using `clearTimeout`, I've added that to the above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to asign variable to your setinterval;

```
var foo = setTimeout(testTimeout(), 5000);
```

and then when right event comes just destroy that variable.

```
clearInterval(foo);
```

And now you can asign it again...

Answer (score -1):

In your case it would simply repeat endlessly, because you're executing the function instead of passing the reference. You should do it like this:

```
function testTimeout() {
    alert("testing timeout)";
    setTimeout(testTimeout, 5000);
}
```

Note the missing braces after `testTimeout`. This tells `setTimeout` to execute that function, instead of the result of that function, which is how your original code behaved.

" I would like my timeout function to be called right away and every 5 seconds after with my new parameter. But, I don't want the timeout function with the old parameter to continue repeating "

In order to achieve what you're trying to do you should remove the timeout:

```
var timeoutId;
function testTimeout() {
    alert("testing timeout)";
    clearTimeout(timeoutId );
    timeoutId = setTimeout(testTimeout, 5000);
}
```

Notes:

- You can stop the previous timeoutI from firing by catching the id returned from the setTimeout method and passing that to the clearTimeout method

Comment: you can `clearTimeout` too, so there is no need to resort to intervals

Comment: True, I forgot he was calling the same method, which trigger anothers setTimeout